# Merge two SQL SELECT queries results into one query and one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing problem in merging results of two select queries 
i have executed following code in sql, you may try

```
CREATE TABLE #a(a_id int, is_active bit, cr_date date)
CREATE TABLE #b(b_id int, a_id int, cr_date date)

INSERT INTO #a(a_id,is_active, cr_date)
VALUES(1,1,GETDATE()),(2,0,GETDATE()),(3,1,GETDATE()),(4,0,GETDATE()),(5,0,GETDATE())

INSERT INTO #b(b_id,a_id,cr_date)
VALUES(1,1,GETDATE()),(2,1,GETDATE()),(3,4,GETDATE()),(4,4,GETDATE()),(5,4,GETDATE()),(6,4,GETDATE())


CREATE TABLE #c(c_id int, is_active bit, cr_date date)
CREATE TABLE #d(d_id int, c_id int, cr_date date)

INSERT INTO #c(c_id,is_active, cr_date)
VALUES(1,1,GETDATE()),(2,0,GETDATE()),(3,1,GETDATE()),(4,0,GETDATE()),(5,0,GETDATE())

INSERT INTO #d(d_id,c_id,cr_date)
VALUES(1,1,GETDATE()),(2,1,GETDATE()),(3,4,GETDATE()),(4,4,GETDATE()),(5,4,GETDATE()),(6,4,GETDATE())



DECLARE @startDate date;
DECLARE @endDate date;
set @startDate='2012-10-26';
set @endDate=GETDATE();

SELECT 
'#b= '+CAST(COUNT(b.b_id) AS VARCHAR)   b_COUNT,
'#a = '+CAST(COUNT(a.a_id) AS VARCHAR)  a_COUNT  
FROM #a as a LEFT JOIN #b as b    ON a.a_id = b.a_id AND a.is_active = 0
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.cr_date, 111)   BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE

SELECT 
'#d= '+CAST(COUNT(d.d_id) AS VARCHAR)   d_COUNT,
'#c = '+CAST(COUNT(c.c_id) AS VARCHAR)  c_COUNT  
FROM #c as c LEFT JOIN #d as d    ON c.c_id = d.c_id AND c.is_active = 0
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.cr_date, 111)   BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE

for dropping tables 
DROP TABLE #a
DROP TABLE #b
DROP TABLE #c
DROP TABLE #d
```

I got the following result of two select queries

[image: Result of two select queries which are mentioned in question]

Now, I want to merge both results of select queries, but i can't.

any one can tell me how can i merge both queries to get single results in output

Comment: Combine as 2 rows with 2 columns or 1 row with 4 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UNION:

```
SELECT 
'#b= '+CAST(COUNT(b.b_id) AS VARCHAR)   b_COUNT,
'#a = '+CAST(COUNT(a.a_id) AS VARCHAR)  a_COUNT  
FROM #a as a LEFT JOIN #b as b    ON a.a_id = b.a_id AND a.is_active = 0
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.cr_date, 111)   BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
UNION
SELECT 
'#d= '+CAST(COUNT(d.d_id) AS VARCHAR)   d_COUNT,
'#c = '+CAST(COUNT(c.c_id) AS VARCHAR)  c_COUNT  
FROM #c as c LEFT JOIN #d as d    ON c.c_id = d.c_id AND c.is_active = 0
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.cr_date, 111)   BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Comment: I won't use `UNION` due to the fact that you won't have duplicates. You can use `UNION ALL` which is quite faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

Example:

```
SELECT N'A' as col
UNION ALL
SELECT N'B' as col
```

You can use `ALL` to leave the results as they are. Even if there may be duplicates. `ALL` will be faster.

If you leave out `ALL` the query will be checked for duplicates.