# PostgreSQL select different columns based on condition

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to achieve as example below can someone help me out please.

now I am doing like this

```
CREATE TABLE transfers
id               serial,
init_by          varchar(50),
init_to          varchar(50),
to_location      varchar(50),
from_location    varchar(50)

SELECT id, init_to, to_location as location
FROM transfers WHERE init_by = 'abc';

SELECT id, init_from, from_location as location
FROM transfers WHERE init_to = 'abc';
```

Now I need to query 2 times and then merge both results.
How can I achieve it in single query
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UNION` or `UNION ALL`?

Comment: You can use UNION to combine the results , refer the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-union.html)

Comment: sorry really I don't have any idea. how can I achieve that.

Comment: SELECT id, init_to, to_location as location
FROM transfers WHERE init_by = 'abc'
UNION 
SELECT id, init_from, from_location as location
FROM transfers WHERE init_to = 'abc';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine results of two queries into a single dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230350/how-to-combine-results-of-two-queries-into-a-single-dataset) [Merge two SQL SELECT queries results into one query and one result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30938721/1048572) Or even better [How do I combine 2 select statements into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542705/1048572)

Comment: By the way, your table doesn't have the init_from column..did you mean it as init_by ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, my bad

Comment: Thanks to all UNION worked perfectly.

Comment: No need for `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.  Just use [an `OR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-logical.html) in your `WHERE` clause:  `SELECT id, init_to, to_location as location
FROM transfers WHERE init_by = 'abc' OR init_to = 'abc';`